# How to stop value changes on UISlider triggering UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uislider

I have a standard iPad splitView screen, in a storyboard. In portrait orientation, the masterViewController is shown in a popover, as is standard. To the detailView I've added an UISlider (in IB), with its action (Sent Events -> Value Changed) connected to an IBAction method on the detailViewController. When I drag the slider, it sends events to the IBAction method, with is fine: the problem is that the popover also pops up. This even happens when I drag outside the slider: the master popover keeps popping up like an over-enthusiastic puppy.

I've tried subclassing UISlider to intercept beginTrackingWithTouch and continueTrackingWithTouch and I've tried overriding hitTest: to intercept touches originating outside the slider and stop touches inside the slider from percolating but to no avail: the popover thinks it's controlled by the slider. I've downloaded Apple's sample project [Popovers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Popovers/Introduction/Intro.html) on which I was able to replicate this behavior simply but adding an UISlider to the DetailView.xib (non-storyboard). How do I tame this popover?

Comment: Since  it happens even when you drag outside of the slider, it sounds like the issue is unrelated to the UISlider/TBSlider.

Comment: You might think so, but when I remove the slider, the popover doesn't respond to any dragging.